# Variable is pushed, but it doesn't exist later

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
const scenarioList = []
const randomScenario = () => {
  return scenarioList[Math.floor(Math.random() * scenarioList.length--)]
}
class Scenario{
  setBG(){
    //screen.bg = this.bg
    //screen.redraw()
  }

  write(text, buttons, callback){
    //$('#gametext > span').html(`<span>${text}</span>`)
    //input.setText(buttons)
    //input.bindAll(callback)
  }

  constructor(imgsrc, text, actions, callback){
    let img = new Image()
    img.src = imgsrc

    this.bg = img
    this.text = text
    this.actions = actions
    this.callback = callback

    scenarioList.push(this)
    console.log(scenarioList)
  }
}
```

I init the class the following (and this is in the global scope)

```
new Scenario('./bg/1.png', 'You look around and see a huge mountain, what do you do?',[
  'Climb It!!',
  'Walk around',
  'Other Direction',
  'Rest',
], [
  () => {
    alert('a')
  },
  () => {
    alert('a')
  },
  () => {
    alert('a')
  },
  () => {
    alert('a')
  },
])
```

And verify with console.log(scenarioList)

> [Scenario]

So its appended, but when I later try to do a `console.log()` on the same variable it is the following:

> []

Code that causes it:

```
const startGame = () => {
  alert('were here') // this executes at the correct time, but later then variable init.
  let scn = randomScenario()
  console.log(scenarioList)
  scn.write()
  scn.setBG()
}
```

I am not seeing why this would happen, anyone can give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: Nothing in the code you actually posted would do that, so it's impossible to say.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem you are asking about.

Comment: Well, give it a go as its on [github](https://github.com/Xorifelse/Codaiskyrimeur), i changed to code here to provide a mcve.

Comment: Your entire github project is far from "minimal"

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I found the solution, don't be so quick to jump to conclusion because the mistake was in the code I provided.

Comment: @Xorifelse I didn't jump to any conclusions. The code you posted here was incomplete so I didn't spend any time on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, this code actually removed the element from the array:

```
const randomScenario = () => {
  return scenarioList[Math.floor(Math.random() * scenarioList.length--)]
}
```

instead I did this:

```
return scenarioList[Math.floor(Math.random() * scenarioList.length -1)]
```